# Matrix representation of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am given a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[X]_{\leq 2}$ where $L(1 + 2X) = 3 + 3X + 2X^2$ , $L(1 + X) = 1 + X + X^2$ and $L(X^2) = -2 -2X - X^2$ . i want to find a matrix representation  $L_{s}^{s}$ where $s$ is a standard basis ${(1 , X,X^2)}$.

The confusing part is that $L$ takes 3 different parameters and gives 3 different images for each of them and i think i have to find a general linear map first then i can find matrix of linear transformation. Is it correct?

I have no idea how to approach this problem. Can someone explain a little bit instead of giving full solution.

Thanks

Comment: What are $L(1)$, $L(X)$, and $L(X^2)$?

Comment: The vector space is real valued polynomials of degree$\leq$2.

Comment: @Luai Ghunim If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to **translate in vectors language**, you know that:
$$(1,2,0)\to(3,3,2)\\
(1,1,0)\to(1,1,1)\\
(0,0,1)\to(-2,-2,-1)$$

From here it's easy to **find a matrix representation**.

In this simple case you can do it directly as follow.

From the third condition you already know that the third  column of the matrix is $(-2,-2,-1)$.

Subtracting the second from the first you obtain:

$$(0,1,0)\to(2,2,1)$$

thus you also know that the second column of the matrix is $(2,2,1)$.

At this point you know that:

$$(0,1,0)\to(2,2,1)\\
(1,1,0)\to(1,1,1)\\
(0,0,1)\to(-2,-2,-1)$$

Finally subtracting the new first from the second:

$(1,0,0)\to(-1,-1,0)$

that's the first column of the matrix representation.

Thus the solution is:

\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & -2 \\
-1 & 2 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

**More in general** let consider a map such that:

$$L(\vec v_i)=\vec w_i$$

We are interested to find the matrix which represent this map, that is

$$A\vec v_i=\vec w_i$$

Now the question is: **How to find A?**

Consider for simplicity the case n=3 (but it can be extended in general).

We are looking for tha matrix A such that:

$$A\vec v_1=\vec w_1$$
$$A\vec v_2=\vec w_2$$
$$A\vec v_2=\vec w_3$$

Put vectors $\vec v_i$ as columns in the matrix M and vectors$\vec w_i$ as columns in the matrix N, the we can write:

$$AN=M$$

Now calculate $N^{-1}$

and finally find

$$A=MN^{-1}$$

Comment: **Subtracting the second from the first you obtain** here why would i subtract ?  Can you please write a formula , how we move from a matrix representation of some bases b -> standard basis to a matrix from standard bais to standard basis.

Comment: The manipulations have been done in order to obtain the mapping of the standard vectors. In this way you can write down the matrix of L putting in the first row the result for L(1,0,0), in the second L(0,1,0), in the third L(0,0,1). Certainly it can be done purely by matrix operations. Are you interested in it?

Comment: @LuaiGhunim I've added a full explanation to find matrix A in matrix notation! Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: thanks for the extra explaination :)

Comment: You are welcome, if you need any other explanation feel free to ask, Thanks!

Comment: Why $v_i's$ should be written as columns in **M** and not in **N**?

Comment: @KhanSaab we need to do so to write the systems in matrix form

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use a a linear combination of $1+2X,1+X,$ and $X^2$ to get your basis $1,X,$ and $X^2$, and then use linearity of $L$ to find what their values are.

Answer (score 1):

$s=(1,x,x^2)$, $b=(1+2x,1+x,x^2)$

$M(L$, input $b$, output $s) = \begin{Bmatrix}
3 & 1 & -2 \\
3 & 1 & -2 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{Bmatrix}$

$M(L$, input $s$, output $s)=M(L$, input $b$, output $s)*M($Id, input $s$, output $b)$.

Now $M($Id, input $s$, output $b)=M($Id, input $b$, output $s)^{-1}$ and

$M($Id, input $b$, output $s)=\begin{Bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 \\
2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{Bmatrix}$

Now find the inverse and multiply.